# Python's Subprocess.Popen With Shell=True. Wait till it is completed

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

Submitting a complex **cmd** string made of a full file path to an executable, the multiple flags, arguments, parameters, inputs and outputs seems to require me to set **shell=True** otherwise subprocess.Popen is not able understand anything more complex than just a simple path to executable (with no spaces in a filepath).

In my example I have quite a long cmd:

```
cmd = " '/Application/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/my_executable' '/Path/to/input/files' -some -flags -here -could -be -a -lot '/full/path/to/output/files' "
```

Submitting this cmd to **subprocess.Popen** " results to an error that complains on something about the path and not being able to find it.

So instead of using :

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

**check_call** seems workings quite well:

```
proc = subprocess.check_call(cmd, shell=True)
```

Interesting, only after **shell** is set to **True**

```
shell=True
```

the **subprocess.check_call** works with a supplied cmd.

The side effect is that the rest of the code seems proceeds running without waiting for **subprocess.check_call(cmd, shell=True)** to finish first.

The code is designed the way that the rest of the execution is dependent on a result of `subprocess.check_call(cmd, shell=True)`.

I wonder if there is anyway to enforce the code execution to wait till subprocess.check_call(cmd, shell=True) is finished. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried converting the `cmd` into a list when running with `shell=False` and `subprocess.Popen`? You could use the `shlex.split()` function to do that, like in the example code provided in the [documentation of the Popen constructor](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @mikkas suggest just use it as a `list` here is a working example:

```
mainProcess = subprocess.Popen(['python', pyfile, param1, param2], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

# get the return value from the method
communicateRes = mainProcess.communicate()

stdOutValue, stdErrValue = communicateRes
```

You are calling `python.exe pyfile param1 param2`

By using `communicate()` you can get the `stdout` and `stderr` as a `Tuple`

You can use python method `split()` to split your string to a list for example:

```
cmd = "python.exe myfile.py arg1 arg2"

cmd.split(" ")
```

Output:

```
['python.exe', 'myfile.py', 'arg1', 'arg2']
```

Comment: Avoid `cmd.split(' ')` because it cannot handle quotes. Use `shlex.split` instead, which knows the syntax used for shell's commands and thus it can handle things like `'program "a single argument with quotes"'` as expected.

Comment: Nice didn't know that

Answer (score 1):

I think the check_call function should wait for the command to finish.

See the docs here
http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: I need to read the stdout of the process running. Does subprocess.check_call allow to read its stdout? If so would you please clarify how to accomplish this.

Comment: why don't you try using subprocess.check_output instead?

Answer (score 1):

Check call does not wait. You need to do a process.wait() and check the return code explicitly to get the functionaly you want.

```
Process = subprocess.Popen('%s' %command_string,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
            Process.wait()
            if Process1.returncode!=0:
                    print Process1.returncode
                    sendMail()
                    return
            else:
                    sendMail()
```